# how to pass an table row object directly to another html page as url argument?

Tags: javascript, html, function

sample.html

```
<html>
.....
 <tr onclick="callnxtpg(this)">
 </tr>
.....
<script>
function callnxtpag(obj){
window.location="someotherlocation.html&obj="+obj;
}
</script>
```

someotherlocation.html

```
<html>
...
<script>
var obj=returnData(obj);
alert(obj.childNodes[0].innerHTML);
</script>
....
</html>
```

My question is is it possible to do passing one page's element object to another directly in any way?

Comment: 16 questions and not a single accepted? And you expect us to just continue to help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass text within the URL, you won't be able to place an object in there unless that object is a string or numeric.
You could use a cookie to save the object and retrieve it on the next page.

Comment: I am not sure about the session...I think that too only takes and stores string value...can we really store objects other than string in session??

Comment: You definitely can in a .NET session - I suppose that's a little off what the OP said.

Comment: I was taking of JAVA session...may be its not possible in all technology

Answer (score 0):

No, the query sting only takes string as input...so you cannot put an object in the URL query string

You need to send the table as a string with the query string....

Answer (score 0):

Consider that many browsers and servers have a 4k byte limit on the length of an url. Consider [client-side storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278467/persistent-storage-on-client-side) an an alternative.