# Jquery Countdown Timer no reset on page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, pdo

I have a piece of code that works flawlessly. When a button is pressed the timer counts down until it can be pressed again.

**The problem**: When the page is refreshed it will be reset and they will have to click it all over again before the count down happens again.

**The Goal**: The timer to start back at whatever time they have left.

My application is `PHP` and `MySQL` if that would work best but here is the code I'm working with.

Does anyone know how I'd get the functionality I'm looking for?

**JS**

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).html('show')
    $('.show').slideUp('medium');
    var count = 10,
        counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
        count--;
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            $('.trigger').html('hide');
            $('.show').slideDown('medium');
            return;
        }
        console.log(count);
        $('.timer').html(count);
    }
});
```

Comment: just a suggestion, you can still use the real time against this, so if the user refreshes it doesnt matter because your functionality goes against the real time

Comment: @GunrJesra This won't allow for the counter to continue, since you have no other time to compare with therefore you are unable to do a timespan compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish your goal there are two methods:

**Cookies or DataStorage**: This method is good if you can trust your clients.

[Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

[JavaScript Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

[StackOverflow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278467/persistent-storage-on-client-side)

**Database Storage**: You can do an ajax call to your backend and store the users click.  The problem with this method is that ever second you have to resend to the database.

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

The reason you are seeing what you are seeing:

The process flow looks like this:

> Server Side code -> sends data to client -> browser begins rendering and executing JS

You are on the last step, since the web is stateless you don't store the information in the JavaScript client front end.  You will have to do one of the above to solve this.

Using the above information below is an *example* tailored to you:

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/5LWgN/)

**JS**

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

$('.trigger').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).html('show')
    $('.show').slideUp('medium');
    var count = 10;
    if (readCookie("timer") != undefined) count = readCookie("timer");

    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
        createCookie("timer", count, 365);
        count--;
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            $('.trigger').html('hide');
            $('.show').slideDown('medium');
            eraseCookie("timer");
            return;
        }
        console.log(count);
        console.log(readCookie("timer"));
        $('.timer').html(count);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about HTML5 storage... might use it in a new project.

Comment: Alright well in that case, is there a way for me to make sure before they leave the page or refresh the page give them a warning there will be a 60 second delay upon return and then make the time for 60 seconds once they return? Problem is I dont want to do database calls every second but the members cant be trusted if one figures out how to change the cookies every other member will be at a disadvantage.

Comment: @Jorge It definitely is awesome, but unfortunately doesn't support older IEs.

Comment: @user2579862 absolutely, you'll want to catch on page leave: $(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );

Comment: actually what would the cookie route look like?

Comment: @user2579862 i've included a cookie example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Javascript doesn't persists the state. It starts from 0 on each page load.

For the functionality you need, you should save a cookie on click at timer STOP button and read it on page load to see if it has a value saved or not, then start from second 0.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html